# Call to undefined method SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::driver()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on api part in Laravel 5.2 and trying to fetch the details from Strava. As mentioned in this link http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/strava I have done all the steps. In the controller I wrote a function to pass the access token of the user. This is the function which I am using public function

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Socialite;
use App\Models\UserTrackerSettings;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class StravaController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Get the user by token
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function getTrackerAccess()
    {
        $trackerDriver = Socialite::driver('strava');
        $getToken = UserTrackerSettings::where('tracker_source_name', 'strava')
                        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

        $access_token = $getToken->access_token;

        return Socialite::getUserByToken($access_token);
    }
}
```

But when I run the the link in postman I am getting this error

> FatalErrorException in StravaController.php line 23:
>   Call to undefined method SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::driver()

It would be great if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install `   "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",` ? Also ensure that `strava` exists as a driver. I am sure there is no support for `strava` in socialite 2.0

Comment: Yes,I have installed "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
        "socialiteproviders/strava": "^1.1"

and done the steps mentioned in this url http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/strava/

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: have you added `SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider` to your config/app.php under providers?

Comment: @Digitlimit - yes I have added

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the actual `driver` is in there. Afterwards, since I don't see any class inclusions in there, you might need to call that class like this `\App\Socialite::driver('strava')` or just `\Socialite::driver('strava')`, I just don't know if that is the full code for your controller or not.

Comment: Also I have added as you have mentioned but still no change

Comment: Did you check if you have the `driver` function in there? Can we see the Socialite class code in here?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant by Socialite class code